# TexStudio shows me greenish spots on the scrolling bar, what does this mean and how do I remove them?

Tags: texstudio

As seen in the joined screenshot below, I have lots of green spots on my scrolling bar, which sometimes appear.

What do these correspond to, and can I get rid of them?

[image]

Comment: Is the "Find" bar open?

Comment: @campa, looks like as in screenshot.

Comment: @Sigur Oh, right! Hadn't noticed that.

Comment: @campa Oooooh, that seems to be it. So simple, yet I had no idea what this could be. Indeed, searching for something creates these green blocks (or lines rather) to show every line where the searched for term is located. You may answer this if you like.